# How to setup a project to run using JNLP?

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp

I currently have an application that runs from the desktop, but I would like to make it deployable from web browsers using JNLP. How do you go about setting up jnlp for an application? Are there any examples that go more in depth then a hello world?

Comment: See the [info. page for JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for the best links I could find to tutorials.  *"Are there any examples that go more in depth then a hello world?"*  Probably not, but why would you need that?  Or what specifically beyond 'deploying a Hello World application by JWS' are you interested in knowing more about?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was mostly just wanting some examples for specifying resources etc and the few examples I found didn't have much on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up following this reference http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jnlp-142088.html to build my jnlp. On a side note to add more jars etc all you need to do is list more jar tags and tag one as main. Use this to reference the structure and required tages https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html#extension